# Mostrar imagenes desde una base de datos en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Tengo un modelo que tiene un campo imagen, al principio se mostraba la imagen, pero despues que hice unos cuantos cambios pero sin modificar el codigo que sirve la imagen ahora no me funciona, he probado de todo pero no funciona, este es el codigo del setting:

```
setting.py
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
```

este es la url.py
    from django.views.static import serve

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),]
```

y esto es mi plantilla

Omito el otro codigo por considerarlo innecesario para esto.

Answer (score 2):

Recomiendo que eches un vistazo en la documentación oficial y intentarlo como indica: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: No funciona, y ahora que veo esto aparece en el log "GET /view/equipo/media/logos/redsox.png HTTP/1.1" 404 33

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo Django 1.11.6  Con Python 3.6

En settings.py lo tengo asi:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Y en las URLs

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# Examples:

url(r'^verarchivo/$', app.views.VerArchivosView, name='verArchivo'),

url(r'^contact$', app.views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^about', app.views.about, name='about')
# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

O asi pero esto era cuando tenia Django 1.7 en el proyecto

```
if settings.DEBUG:
# static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
urlpatterns.append(
    # /media/:<mixed>path/
    url(
        regex=r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
        view='django.views.static.serve',
        kwargs={'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))'''
```